# Usage of git rebase

Tags: git

Suppose I have a `feature` branch which is created from a `development` branch.

After some time, there are new commits to the `development` branch.

I want to apply those commits back to my `feature` branch so that it is as if my `feature` branch is based on the latest `development` branch.

To do so, as it to use the following git command ?

```
git pull origin //getting all latest updates
git checkout -b my-feature-branch //navigate to my feature branch
git rebase development //apply those delta commits back to my feature branch
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct command to rebase `feature` to the latest `development` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be following these steps, assuming you are starting off on the `feature` branch:

```
git fetch origin                 # update origin/development with latest changes
git rebase origin/development    # rebase on latest development
# resolve conflicts, etc.
git push --force origin feature  # overwrite remote feature with local version
```

Note that I avoid doing a `git pull` here, since by default that might be doing a merge somewhere, which you probably don't want.  Also, notice in the final step we are doing a force push.  This is required as the history of `feature` has been rewritten.  Therefore, a regular (non force) push would fail as the histories do not line up properly.